# "a generation of future potential" or "the future potential of a generation"

Tags: meaning, phrase-usage, possessives

I come across the title of a UNICEF report "Children's Exposure to Lead Pollution Undermines a Generation of Future Potential" [Blockquote](https://www.unicef.org/reports/toxic-truth-childrens-exposure-to-lead-pollution-2020)

I do not understand the use of “a Generation of Future Potential”, which equals "future potential's a generation" and it doesn't make sense to me. Why wouldn't it be "the future potential of a generation"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equality is not quite correct.

In the phrase *a generation of future potential*, "*of*" does not indicate possession.

[**"Of" can have a lot of meanings**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/of), in this case two might apply.

1. "**used after words or phrases expressing amount, number, or a particular unit**:" A generation can be a measurement of time, defined to be about 25 years. In this case, the phrase is another way to say "***25 years of future potential***".
2. "**made or consisting of; having:**" In this meaning, the phrase is another way of saying "***a generation that has future potential***" (or given the context "a generation that would have future potential, if it were not undermined")